# What is a previous transaction?

Tags: transactions

I'm new in the bitcoin field and I need to understand about transactions.
When Bob is sending bitcoins to Alice, Bob will create a tx, he will add Alice's address, sign it and broadcast it in the network. But what is the previous transaction in this case? Is it a different tx from the one between Bob and Alice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the transaction (or transactions) that bob got his bitcoins from.

Comment: What if that previous transaction is old? Does this matter?

Comment: @user2016355 If the previous transaction is old, then the bitcoin network will give the new transaction special treatment.

Comment: Thanks Nick. Is it possible to explain more? is there any link that I can read on the internet for that special treatment?

Comment: @user2016355 https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_fees Look for "Technical info"